# Modifying the string list using reflection

Tags: c#, string, list, reflection

Say, I have a class User which has (string FirstName, List siblings)
I want to modify the properties of the user.

Let's assume that I want to replace the strings with b instead of a.

user : {
firstname: "Rager",
siblings : {
"stalin",
"Marx"
} }

using reflection I need to read the individual strings and the following would be the output object.

user : {
firstname: "Rbger",
siblings : {
"stblin",
"Mbrx"
} }

Let's consider the below function

```
private object modifyObject(object t){
   foreach(var propertyInfo in t.GetType.GetProperties(){
      var stringToBeModified = propertyInfo.GetValue(t,null);
      propertyInfo.SetValue(t, stringToBeModified.replace("a","b"),null)
   }
}
```

The above code works fine when modifying the firstName. But dont know how to modify the strings in siblings.

I thought I will make use of the 3rd property (optional index value for the indexed properties). But it looks like the whole property was not indexed. 
for siblings, propertyInfo.GetValue(t,null) gives 2 strings.

```
[0] -- stalin
[1]  -- Marx.
```

Can anyone tell me how I can modify the above 2 strings after getting the value using propertyInfo.GetValue(t,null)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply cast the value as `List<string>` and update as desired

eg

```
List<string> list = (List<string>)propertyInfo.GetValue(t,null);
list[0] = list[0].replace("a","b");
```

above sample is assuming the propertyInfo of siblings which is of type `List<string>`, you may adjust as needed.

Comment: Can I have a dynamic type. Say propertyInfo.GetValue(t,null) can either return a list of int or list of string or list of bool. In that case how do I do cast it?

Comment: @Bala, since int, string and bool are not compatible to each other and you may not have common logic to handle all of them. you can check the property type and execute the code conditionally. see [PropertyInfo.PropertyType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype(v=vs.110).aspx)